# How to reduce the size of video file as a buffer or blob before writing it on Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I send live feed from client to the server using websocket from the client side like this :

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(canvasStream, {
        mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9',
        videoBitsPerSecond: 3 * 1024 * 1024
    });
    recorder.ondataavailable = async (e) => {
        const arbuf = await e.data.arrayBuffer()
        ws.send(pack({ type: 'REC', data: arbuf })) //sends to server
    }
```

and on the server side I get them like this :

```
 let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'video/mp4' })
      const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer());
      fs.writeFile("foo.mp4", buffer, () => console.log('video saved!'));
```

However `foo.mp4` is really large. Please help me find a way to reduce the size of `foo.mp4` as it is being written down to the disc. ( I can reduce it after it is written, however that won't do the trick for me. It has to be encoded and compressed before it is written )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is possible to do, but you can try [fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg).
And then you can use streams like this:

```js
ffmpeg(readableStream);

// or
ffmpeg(fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file.avi'));
```

Comment: This doesn't reduce the file size, does it?

Comment: You can reduce it using different filters, codecs, resolutions, video sizes, etc. It depends on your source video and what you wish to get as a result. You can dive into the official documentation of [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) and [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg).